# Google App Engine Server IP adresses

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm migrating our system to the Google App Engine.

When our PDF generator needs a external resource (for example a picture) it does an internal HTTP request (where the request IP is different from the user IP). It then also starts an different session, so I cannot see if the user is logged.
In order to give the right permissions, I need to check if the request comes from a server IP.

In the previous code I checked this trough the following code:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) {
  return true;
}
```

But since $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is not available, this cannot be used.

In the new code I check this trough the following code:

```
$allowed_ips = array(
   '127.0.0.1',
   '8.35.201.100'
);

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed_ips)) { return true; }
```

The problem is; I do not know which IP addresses Google App Engine uses to do a internal request.
I have found the IP address 8.35.201.100 as a server address, but are there more IP addresses or maybe ranges.

The Task Queues Google App Engine issues requests from the IP address 0.1.0.2 (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push#Task_Execution). Is this the same at the internal request.

Greets, Hendrik

Comment: you could use the request headers instead of IP adresses, the header tells you that this request comes from appengine and it also tells you the appengine appID, so you can identify your own appengine app

Comment: how do I get this request headers? I tried several ways ($_SERVER, getallheaders()) but no one gives me the request origin and appID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think AppEngine discloses IP addresses.  AppEngine is a dynamic environment with instances spinning up and spinning down, there would be requests from different IPs as things change.

When you make HTTP requests from AppEngine, it does set a few header fields to mark that the request was from AppEngine.  I think the AppId is included.  Anyway here is the documentation on that.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#Request_Headers

From a security standpoint, anyone can just write fake HTTP headers.  So I wouldn't rely on that as a means of authentication.